# Copy the same content to every new sheet plus check for duplicates

Tags: vba

Here was my previous query: [vba code - copy cells above when value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382125/vba-code-copy-cells-above-when-value-changes/45393922#45393922)

Thst helped, but I would like to add one more thing if possible. I need to copy a few the same lines to every newly created sheet (these lines are on the 1st active sheet).The lines are the same for every new sheet and would be around 2 lines below the data populated by the above macro. Also i would like to chech this column for duplicates. So the column would include: Data populated by the macro plus the same pre-set lines for every new sheet plus a check for duplicates in this column. The result would show not duplicated values so that i know i need to add them to my application☺ How would I add this to a code?:)

would the below fit somewhere?

```
Sheets("Results".Range("A1:A36").Copy Destanation:=Sheets(Activeworkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Dears, will you be able to help?

Comment: I am trying to figure out myself..and i do not know where to put the copying and duplicates code.

Comment: Provide the input and output details in a sheet

Comment: I need to have the same range of cells copied below the newly created sheet by the macro from the linked question. And after this I would like to highlight the duplicates. 
Which input and output do you have in mind?

Comment: To be more precise: The macro would;
1. Go throuh the column H  and if the value changes - copies the previous rows from the column C. 
2. THen, it would add these values to the new sheet plus the values from the sheet "core data" - core data is the first sheet with the predefined rows. 
3. Then as a result the column would have the values from volumn C and pre defined rows. 
4. The macro would make a check for duplicates on this column in every new sheet (new values plus pre defined in one column)

As a result i would kno which are duplicates. 

I hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: anyone would help  ?